# Notepad ++ syntax highlighting not working when using sqlite3 in python

Tags: python, sqlite, notepad++

sqlite3 syntax highlighting isn't working when writing python code in Notepad ++, here is an example code:

```
import sqlite3
import re
conn = sqlite3.connect('org_db.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('''
CREATE TABLE Counts (org TEXT, count INTEGER)''')
```

For example in the code above things like "CREATE TABEL" and "TEXT" are not highlighted!

Comment: that's cause it is highlighting python not sqlite3 ... additionally  I think no matter what that ends up highlighting as a string literal

Comment: I just used Atom v 1.0 and it did highlight sqlite stuff inside a .py file

Comment: well I cant run atom in my environment ... but I doubt it was inside a string literal when it was highlighted... I could be wrong ... if atom solves your problem then perhaps the answer is to use atom ... I suppose there might be some plugin for notepad++ ... but I doubt it

Comment: It takes a lot of guesswork for an application to highlight SQL within a Python string. You are expecting too much. If Atom does that and similar tricks, especially if it does it well, I'm impressed. Why then do you use Notepad++? ;)

Comment: I started to learn programming few weeks ago. I prefere to use Notepad, I think it's more simple than Atom. For example I wasn't able to find a way to change Atom's backgroud to white instead of dark grey, it's a little confusing with all these packages and themes.

Comment: You could work with two files: One python and one sql. In the sql-File you would write down your sql-statements with proper highlighting and when finished, you copy/paste the statements into the string in the python file. It is a "dirty hack" and not very comfortable, but it is simple and easy to try.

Comment: @LarsFischer   That will do for now. Anyone knows a plugin for Notepad ++ that can help with this issue.